# Регистр ключей массива information_schema MySQL

Tags: mysql

В ответ на запрос типа

```
SELECT *
FROM `information_schema`.`columns`
WHERE `table_schema`="..." AND `table_name`="..." ORDER BY `ordinal_position` ;
```

Один сервер выдаёт массив с ключами в верхнем регистре, типа:

```
[COLUMN_NAME] => ot_id;
[COLUMN_COMMENT] => ha-ha;
[DATA_TYPE] => int;
```

А другой сервер выдаёт массив с ключами в нижнем регистре, типа:

```
[column_name] => ot_id;
[column_comment] => ha-ha;
[data_type] => int;
```

ВОПРОС: какой параметр сервера MySQL отвечает за эти настройки? Как можно ими управлять? Или это PHP?

Comment: первый наверное на mysql8 а второй на 5 ?

Comment: а второй:
Localhost via UNIX socket
Тип сервера: MariaDB
Версия сервера: 10.3.31-MariaDB-cll-lve - MariaDB Server
Версия протокола: 10